# xmpp pubsub not delivering messages

Tags: xmpp, publish-subscribe, strophe

I'm building a simple web tool with the lattest Strophe.js to handle pubsub messages. I can create nodes, subscribe, see forms... but when I publish (with ok response from server) messages are never forwarded to subscribed clients

I'm using ejabberd server with docker [rroemhild/docker-ejabberd](https://github.com/rroemhild/docker-ejabberd) It has BOSH, pubsub, admin... and seems to be very complete. I have tried also with an standard jabber ubuntu installation with the same results.

I log in with two users and in the first I can create a node, see subscriptions.

```js
$('#create-node').bind('click', function () {
    var pub = $iq({ type: 'set', to: pubsubUrl })
        .c('pubsub', { xmlns: 'http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub' })
        .c('create', { node: nodeName() });
    connection.sendIQ(pub, pubSuccess, pubError, 5000);
});

$('#list-subscriptions-node').bind('click', function () {
    var pub = $iq({ type: 'get', to: pubsubUrl, from: jid() })
        .c('pubsub', { xmlns: 'http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#owner' })
        .c('subscriptions', { node: nodeName() });
    connection.sendIQ(pub.tree(), pubSuccess, pubError, 5000);
});
```

With the second user I subscribe to a recently created node and I efectively see the second user subscribed.

```js
$('#subscribe-node').bind('click', function () {
    var pub = $iq({ type: 'set', to: pubsubUrl })
        .c('pubsub', { xmlns: 'http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub' })
        .c('subscribe', { node: nodeName(), jid : jid() });
    connection.sendIQ(pub, pubSuccess, pubError, 5000);
});
```

Finally I publish some message. I get an OK response from the server.

```js
$('#publish-node').bind('click', function () {
    var pub = $iq({ type: 'set', to: pubsubUrl, from: jid() })
        .c('pubsub', { xmlns: 'http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub' })
        .c('publish', { node: nodeName() })
        .c('item')
        .c('x', {xmlns :'jabber:x:data', type: 'result'})
        .c('field', {var : 'title'})
        .c('value').t($('#node-event').val());
    connection.sendIQ(pub, pubSuccess, pubError, 5000);
});
```

My full code app is [this github repo](https://github.com/guillemsola/ejabberd-PoC) in case you want to play/see all the code.

Now the question is, despite everything seems to be fine I cannot see any message from the server to subscribed clients to a pubsub node... I tested with MUC conversations and everything is fine. **When I publish node messages those are never sent as messages to clients.**

I've Checked with several examples and books and I cannot understand if I'm doing something wrong or it's a server configuration thing.

Any idea? Is there somewhere in the server where I can check what's going on under the hoods?

Some examples from my server calls. Confirming that a user is subscribed

```
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'>
    <iq xmlns='jabber:client' from='pubsub.example.com' to='guillem@example.com/13675173711451438137658982' id='3:sendIQ' type='result'>
        <pubsub xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#owner'>
            <subscriptions node='4193886472'>
                <subscription jid='admin@example.com' subscription='subscribed' subid='5AB6AF973AC7E'/>
            </subscriptions>
        </pubsub>
    </iq>
</body>
```

And here a succesfully published message

```
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'>
    <iq xmlns='jabber:client' from='pubsub.example.com' to='guillem@example.com/13675173711451438137658982' id='5:sendIQ' type='result'>
        <pubsub xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub'>
            <publish node='4193886472'>
                <item id='5AB6AFAB19CFD'/>
            </publish>
        </pubsub>
    </iq>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that messages are not delivered to a connected user until it has not showed his presence.

```
<presence xmlns='jabber:client'>
    <priority>1</priority>
</presence>
```

Presence has to be a positive value.